# UWP Speech Recognition Topic Constraint property topicHint

Tags: c#, uwp, speech-recognition, speech, speech-recognition-api

When declare a new constraint with the class SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint i need to specify the scenario and the context(topicHint) in this way.

```
var constraint = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.Dictation, "topicHint");
```

or

```
var constraint = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.WebSearch, "topicHint");
```

or

```
var constraint = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.FormFilling, "topicHint");
```

according to the type of scenario.

My doubt is based on topicHint because in the net I have seen different terms (ex. "dictation","Phone number","Person Name","webSearch","address"), but I have not found information on which ones are available and their actual function in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the schema for the VCD file
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/voicecommands/voice-command-elements-and-attributes-1-2

There you can find the valid values for subjects, which are:

> "Date/Time", "Addresses", "City/State", "Person Names", "Movies", "Music", and "Phone Number"

Also valid values for scenarios are

> "Natural Language"
>   "Search"
>   "Short Message"
>   "Dictation"
>   "Commands"
>   "Form Filling"